# NginX "proxy_ssl_certificate" questions, what is it used for?

Tags: nginx, ssl

It's not entirely clear from the documentation how to use the proxy_ssl_certificate directives.

I have this kind of setup:

Server InternalA <---HTTPS---> Server NginxB <----HTTPS---->  remote-website-A

Server NginxB needs to forward GET/POST (generated in InternalA) to the remote-website and return results using SSL.

My NginxB server is running with SSL on + all certs prepared.

However, under the "location {" tag for the proxying to remote-website-A, I need to set further settings for SSL correct? Would they simply match the SSL settings above the "location" tags?

```
#proxy_ssl_certificate src.crt;
#proxy_ssl_certificate_key srv.key;
#proxy_ssl_ciphers TLSv1.2;
#proxy_ssl_password_file keyfile.pz;
#proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
#proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate root.crt;
#proxy_ssl_verify on;
```

Or are these proxy_ssl directives used for individuals who use my proxy?

**The question: Will server NginxB SSL-handshake successfully two-way SSL with remote-website-A without setting the proxy_ssl parameters?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_certificate) says "Specifies a file with the certificate in the PEM format used for authentication to a proxied HTTPS server." This suggests if you're not doing client certificate authentication can ignore it.

If you want help with an actual problem you should specify the problem better. It looks like you're looking for architectural or design advice.

You haven't outlined if you have a problem, you've just said what you're trying to achieve. If there's a problem with this kind of think I'd expect to see:

- a curl demonstrating the problem
- access and error logs from each application in the stack / chain to give more information
- configuration
- what you've done so far to try to solve the problem yourself.

Suggest you start again and completely rewrite your question.

Comment: My simple question is will it work? Will nginx-server authenticate via SSL handshake with the proxied server (remote-website-A). will server nginxB communicate via ssl to remote-website-A using the parameters set like ssl on; ssl_key= etc. in two-way SSL? I edited question above.

Comment: Are you using client authentication - ie the server ensures it's communicating with a known client identified by a certificate - or regular https where the client could be any machine?

Comment: I think it has to be client-auth, how else would you be sure it's this one specific website communicating right? The other website should have activated verify with CA mode to ensure it's valid two-way SSL. They already have my specific signed cert even though both websites probably have same root-CA. They didn't give much clarification because they're not that smart. I'm trying to deduce the exact specifications without documentation from them. "preventative coding"

Comment: You really need to edit your question to make it clear what you're trying to achieve, not just what you're doing.

Comment: What's not clear about it? SSL two-way, between 2 servers. nginx <--> remote-website.  I want to setup nginx correctly so that its "location {}" proxy sends/forwards POST/GET requests to the remote-website with SSL encryption. That's it. Every other "location {}" tag is already SSL activated and doesn't forward anything anyway it just returns results from nginx. The remote website is awaiting a connection with SSL signed certs ready to present, so that it can return responses to nginx, which will return the response to an internal server (which doesn't need SSL).

Comment: The reason I ask is unless you have a need to authenticate that source server is who they say they are you don't need to use ssl client authentication, just valid certificates. Authentication would presumably need to be mutual. Because you haven't said what you're trying to do at a high level it's difficult to say if that directive is required or not.

Comment: sending encrypted private SSL POST/GET requests to the remote-website from the nginx-server and reading the JSON response... shouldn't that be enough to determine how to approach this?

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous. I see no need for client authentication so you don't need proxy_ssl_certificate, just plain SSL should do it.

Comment: but I have a private key, should I not utilize it in someway here?

Comment: You need a private key and a certificate for regular SSL. Directives are ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key

Comment: Yes thank you. I got all that ready and have activated SSL for nginx using directives. So I am gonna do some tests with it soon. I just wasn't sure of proxy_ssl.